# How to get the compiler call with parameters used by VS2013 during a build

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, build-automation

We are setting up our automated build, it's our first 64 bit C# autobuild.
Long ago I thought I remembered seeing the commandline of the build in the build output, but I don't see it now. I kind of remember the compiler in VS being different than MSBuild...

Is there some way to see what the command line equivalent of the current options in VS are? I want to compile it just like VS2013 does now.

Answer (score 0):

Set the following settings to `Diagnostic` and then inspect the logs that are available in the Output window when you build your solution/projects in Visual Studio.

1. MSBuild project build output verbosity
2. MSBuild project build log file verbosity

[image]

[image]